# After OTA update all my data are in shell folder

Tags: adb, internal-storage, 5.1-lollipop

I have Acer Z530 with Lollipop 5.1, kernel 3.10.65+. I have the 16GB version, without external SD Card.

Today I have received an OTA update and after the restart all my data were gone as well as some 7GB of free space missing on the internal storage. When I connected using `adb` I have found all my data in folder `/mnt/shell/emulated` but the new data are being stored in `/mnt/shell/emulated/0`. So far I was able to find that the **0** is the default directory of the owner user. It seems that this update added the multiuser support, but failed to transfer the data.

How can I easily restore my data? Can I just `mv` everything to the **0** folder?

At this moment I'm `pull`ing the folder to my PC, to have a backup, but I would rather do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `adb shell` and `mv` command I was able to move all data to correct directory. After that, to be sure I did an restart and everything seems to be working correctly.